# transform xml to xsl

Tags: java, android, xml, xslt

I'm calling a web service, it is returning result in XML format. How do I convert returning XML into XSL and display that in web browser?

Comment: XSL is a tool for converting XML into something different (including XML). Are you sure you want to convert XML into XSL? This doesn't really make sense. Also, XSL *is* XML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSL is a language for specifying the visual formatting of an XML document. You cannot extract XSL from XML.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you mean that you wish to transform XML to HTML using XSL transformation (XSLT). If my assumption is correct, see this link: http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2004k/ctl257/JavaXSLT/Ch05.html

or just search "xslt java" in google.

If my assumption is wrong, sorry for missunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You *use* XSLT to convert XML into something else.  XSLT is a full programming language which takes some time to learn, but fortunately is fully available in the current version of Java.

You might find this link interesting: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_xslt_ch5/index.html